Can only the information from the server be transferred to the client using signalr?
The result from my payment service is being posted to the controller that I will specify on the server of my blazor project. What I want to do is to report the posted data live to the client side using signalr. I did everything but it didn't work. Can you help me?
My client razor page:
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/paymentHub"), options =>
        {
            options.AccessTokenProvider = async () => await SessionStorageHelper.GetItemAsync<string>(StorageKey.Token);
            options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.WebSockets; // WebSocket kullanımı
            options.SkipNegotiation = true; // WebSocket kullanmak için
        })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()  // Bağlantı koparsa yeniden bağlanmayı dener
    .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceivePaymentData", async (result) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                // isPaymentReceived = true;
                // PaymentResult = result;
                // await NotifyUser();
                await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); // UI güncellenir
            });

        try
        {
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR bağlantısı başarıyla başlatıldı.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"SignalR bağlantısı başlatılamadı: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

server controller:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PaymentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<PaymentHub> _hubContext;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public PaymentController(IHubContext<PaymentHub> hubContext, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost("callback")]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PaymentCallback([FromForm] OdemeSonucResult sonuc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ödeme sonucu alındı, SignalR ile istemciye gönderiliyor...");

        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivePaymentData", "test test test test");
        return Ok();
    }
}

my hub:
public class PaymentHub : Hub
{
}

my program.cs
using Blazor.Wasm.Client.Helpers;
using Blazor.Wasm.Server.Helper;
using Blazor.Wasm.Server.Hubs;
using DevExpress.XtraCharts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    options.MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 1;
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
})
    .AddJsonProtocol(options => {
        options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    });


builder.Services.TryAddScoped<AppSettingsUpdater>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Open", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithExposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
            .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    });
});

builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

builder.Services.Configure<PaymentAppSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("PD"));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseResponseCompression();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}

app.MapReverseProxy();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("Open");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<PaymentHub>("/paymentHub");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});

app.Run();

The information in the payment system is being sent to my server project, so far there is no problem. I followed this line by putting a breakpoint await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivePaymentData", "test test test test"); There is no exception, no error in the console, but the client side is not triggered.
